# .nupkg does not contains dll of project instead it copies whole project in package after vsts build

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

****i'm building the nuget package using vsts build, once the build is created it does not contains dll of project instead it's just copying whole project in nuget packages.which is not expected****

Comment: Give us more detail. For example, some error messages or some of your IDE environment.

Comment: @SteveFest building my project using vsts build. i have created new build process in vsts under that process i add have different phases 1st phase is of nuget creation using pack command using nuspec file and next phase is copy files where i'm copying build files from vsts to the build artifacts. i could able to build it successfully but when i explore the newly created nuget , it's just copying the project from vsts and i could not able see the bin folder and the dll of my project. am i missing any phase??

Comment: Can you update the question to include how you are building the NuGet package, a sample of what the output you are currently getting and what the output should actually be.

Comment: What's the detail code of nuspec file? What's the result if you run `nuget pack` command in local machine?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Bentley.LogDispatcherProvider</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>xyz</authors>
    <owners>Aarti</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Nuget Package for LogDispatcher Provider</description>
  </metadata>
<files>
    <file src="**\*.*" target="" />
  </files> 
</package>  this is my nuspec file and i want to create nuget package of my project using VSTS build

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: it's working fine now......  @starianchen-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code of nuspec file, you include all files, so all files will be in the package, you need to specify the files/folders that you want to include into the package.

The simple way is that you can specify the **project file** instead of nuspec file to package.